How to optimize an infinite runner game?
I am making an infinite runner game.
Here is the idea how it look like :


Camera stays at 0,0,0 position.
Game uses prefabs chunks with pooling system already.
Dynamic shadows. Baking is possible but it has its own issues. For example seams at chunk borders.
All shaders are srp batcher compatible and frame debugger agree with that.
Only 6 prefabs chunks are visible at the same time, so player can see upcoming obstables and surroundings.
Most of geometry uses just a 4 materials with atlas textures.

Around 500K - 800K triangles could be rendered in the scene. (models aren't optimized at all)
So my question is : how could I reduce the amount of triangles rendered?
Findings:

static batching will not work (world moves)
occlusion culling will not work (same here)
gpu instancing does not work well due to diffenent models used. For example same vertex positions, but different uv in atlas.
automatically merged separate mesh geometry of the same object. (kind of work but triangle count will stay the same, if not more)
modified far clip plane. It works was able to reduce to 200k tris, but no more silhouettes of upcoming buildings.

Ideas (not tried yet):

combine chunk as single mesh with same material, and somehow cut non visible geometry. Possible issue i will have a lot of levels and file size will definetelly increase. Also I think new atlas texture should be generated for each combined chunk.


Make smaller prefabs. 500K triangles in 6 visible prefabs is a lot. subdivide and lod distance items.

"Camera stays at (0,0,0)" Can you explain why you think you need to do that? Do you not think that the gains you'd have by declaring static geometry would potentially be better than not moving the camera? The model-view-projection matrix is still calculated every frame, if I'm not mistaken... you may as well make use of it.

@Engineer this is a infinite runner, I should have precision errors at some point

@Ashkento Well, you could periodically loop the camera's x position back, every few minutes or so (or every set distance, say 100000 units). No need to lock the camera down completely. I'd think that moving large chunks of geometry every frame could get more expensive than moving the camera.

@Engineer that sounds possible, but I think you need to measure not guess.

@Ashkento No, I think you do. Good luck :)


Around 500K - 800K triangles could be rendered in the scene. (models aren't optimized at all)


So my question is : how could I reduce the amount of triangles rendered?

If the models aren't optimized, the best way to reduce the number of triangles is by optimizing the models. Anything else you might do to try to minimize the impact of un-optimized models would be a hack.
You haven't said why you're using models that aren't optimized. The best solution is to have the models optimized by an experienced 3D artist, but if that isn't practical, it's not too difficult to generate LODs in Blender with the Decimate modifier. You do not need any 3D modeling experience to learn how to use Decimate. The results won't look as good as models that are optimized by an artist, but for LODs, you can often get away with the lower quality output of Decimate, especially on mobile where the screen is small.
This isn't a full tutorial, but here's a summary of the workflow:

Import the model file into Blender (File > Import > [format]).
Select a mesh.
Apply the Decimate modifier. Using the default "Collapse" setting, start the "Ratio" setting at about 0.8 and keep reducing it until just before the model starts to look broken. This will be your lowest LOD.
Repeat steps 2 - 3 for each mesh in the model file.
Export the decimated model as an FBX (generally you'll want to set "Apply scalings" to "FBX Unit Scale" in the export dialog)
Repeat steps 2 - 5 with different ratio values to create different LODs.
Set up your LODs in Unity.

For example, let's say that you have a mesh which starts to look broken if you reduce the Decimate ratio below 0.25. Then you might export LOD3 with the ratio at 0.25, LOD2 with the ratio at 0.5, and LOD1 with the ratio at 0.75. How low you can reduce the ratio will completely depend on the mesh; another mesh might start looking broken when the ratio is below 0.6, and then you might skip LOD3 and just do LOD2 at 0.6 and LOD1 at 0.8.
Being able to create your own LODs with Decimate is fairly easy to learn and a very valuable skill if you freelance or are working on a solo project or small team without a dedicated 3D artist.

The lowest form of low LOD are "imposters": You replace the 3d model with just a 2d sprite showing a rendering of the 3d model. This could work very well in a game in that perspective, because upcoming obstacles are only seen from one direction until they get close to the camera.

@Philipp In Unity, they are called "Billboard LODs". There are a few downsides to billboards - they can be a lot of work to set up (having to create a scene and write a script for capturing the images at the right angle and lighting, then adding them as LODs), and they don't work well with lighting changes (obviously not a problem if the scene lighting doesn't change).
